# File encryption and decryption

Tags: python, encryption, python-3.4

So I need pseudo code for this assignment and I have no idea where to start. I am not trying to mooch off you guys, I would just like some guidance on where to start!

Write a program that uses a dictionary to assign “codes” to each letter of the alphabet.

For example:

```
codes = { 'A' : '%', 'a' : '9', 'B' : '@', 'b' : '#', etc...}
```

Using this example, the letter `A` would be assigned the symbol `%`, the letter `a` would be assigned the number `9`, the letter `B` would be assigned the symbol `@`, and so forth.

The program should open a specified text file, read its contents, and then use the dictionary to write an encrypted version of the file’s contents to a second file. Each character in the second file should contain the code for the corresponding character in the first file.

Write a second program that opens an encrypted file and displays its decrypted contents on the screen.

Comment: do you know what pseudo code means?

Comment: Yes i have written pseudo code before, but this assignment is confusing me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic see bullet point three. We will not help with homework questions when no effort is demonstrated.  Try the assignment; use the python docs for dictionaries and file i/o; come back  when you have a minimal, verifiable example of where you got stuck and edit this question.  This is not because we think you are "mooching", or because either party is lazy -- it is to promote higher quality Q&A examples on SO that will be meaningful to future visitors.

Comment: Start by opening the specified file and reading it's contents.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Sure he does, that's why he tagged it '[Python](http://www.searchquotes.com/quotation/If_Python_is_executable_pseudocode,_then_perl_is_executable_line_noise./291677/)' ;)

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo code

1. open a specified text file
2. read its contents
3. then use the dictionary to write an encrypted version of the file’s contents to a second file.

Second program

1. open an encrypted file
2. display its decrypted contents on the screen.

Comment: gribbler wins again (imho at least)

Answer (score 1):

This is so simple it's hard to not just give code. Use `str.translate`. It takes a `dict` mapping inputs to outputs. So open one file in text read mode, the other for text write, read in the input file (either in blocks or all at once), call `.translate(codes)` on it and write out the result of translation.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when I write code I start with comments on what it needs to do.  So for you to do this assignment you should just think about what you have to do instead of how you are going to do it.

You already wrote down some of the what in your question so you just need to continue doing what you started.

As an example:

Open a file
read in a line at a time
process line and convert each character...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but this worked for me.
To encrypt it:

```
encryption_library = {'A':'!','B':'@','C':'#','D':'$','E':'%','F':'^','G':'&','H':'*','I':'(',
                      'J':')','K':'-','L':'_','M':'+','N':'=','O':'`','P':'~','Q':'{','R':'[',
                      'S':'}','T':']','U':':','V':';','W':'"','X':'<','Y':'>','Z':'0','a':'1',
                      'b':'2','c':'3','d':'4','e':'5','f':'6','g':'7','h':'8','i':'9','j':'a',
                      'k':'b','l':'c','m':'d','n':'e','o':'f','p':'g','q':'h','r':'i','s':'j',
                      't':'k','u':'l','v':'m','w':'n','x':'o','y':'p','z':'q'}

orig_file = open('Plain_Text_File.txt','r')
file_read = orig_file.read()    
orig_file.close()
encrypt_file = open('ENCRYPTED_Plain_Text_File.txt','w')

for ch in file_read:
    if ch in encryption_library:
        encrypt_file.write(encryption_library[ch])
    else:
        encrypt_file.write(ch)

encrypt_file.close()
encrypt_file = open('Plain_Text_File.txt','r')
file_read = encrypt_file.read()
encrypt_file.close()
codes_items = encryption_library.items()

for ch in file_read:
    if not ch in encryption_library.values() or ch == '.' or ch == ',' or ch == '!':
        print(ch)
    else:
        for k,v in codes_items:
            if ch == v and ch != '.':
                print(k,end='')
```

To decrypt it:

```
decryption_library = {'!':'A','@':'B','#':'C','$':'D','%':'E','^':'F','&':'G','*':'H','(':'I',
                      ')':'J','-':'K','_':'L','+':'M','=':'N','`':'O','~':'P','{':'Q','[':'R',
                      '}':'S',']':'T',':':'U',';':'V','"':'W','<':'X','>':'Y','0':'Z','1':'a',
                      '2':'b','3':'c','4':'d','5':'e','6':'f','7':'g','8':'h','9':'i','a':'j',
                      'b':'k','c':'l','d':'m','e':'n','f':'o','g':'p','h':'q','i':'r','j':'s',
                      'k':'t','l':'u','m':'v','n':'w','o':'x','p':'y','q':'z'}

orig_file = open('ENCRYPTED_Plain_Text_File.txt','r')
file_read = orig_file.read()
orig_file.close()
encrypt_file = open('DECRYPTED_Plain_Text_File.txt','w')

for ch in file_read:
    if ch in decryption_library:
        encrypt_file.write(decryption_library[ch])
    else:
        encrypt_file.write(ch)

encrypt_file.close()
encrypt_file = open('ENCRYPTED_Plain_Text_File.txt','r')
file_read = encrypt_file.read()
encrypt_file.close()    
codes_items = decryption_library.items()

for ch in file_read:
    if not ch in decryption_library.values() or ch == '.' or ch == ',' or ch == '!':
        print(ch)
    else:
        for k,v in codes_items:
            if ch == v and ch != '.':
                print(k,end='')
```